# How to write a decent report introduction on work you have created?

Tags: research-process, writing, university, undergraduate, introduction

I'm finding it quite difficult to start off a report I have to write. So to write a report you will probably know that you are not allowed to write in first person. But the problem I'm having is writing an introduction not in first person, as the report is to be on the topic on two websites that I have created, one using web standards, and one with a content management system.

I just can't figure out what to point out in the introduction, as there isn't a problem involved, it doesn't really cover a specific question, it's just two websites I have made, that's it.

I don't really know how to explain my problem very well, but hopefully you will understand what I mean, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, despite the conventional wisdom to the contrary, it's actually [often entirely acceptable to write technical documents in the first person](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/scientific-reports/).  Unless you are specifically required to avoid it, it's OK.  Furthermore, even if you can't keep it, you can always start by writing in first person, and then transform to passive voice later.

From there, a good general skeleton of an introduction is sort of a "cone" funneling a reader towards more specific information:

- What is the context for the work that you have done?
- What was the goal for the work?
- What exactly did you accomplish, and how can it be quantified and verified?
- What are the implications of this work?

Finally, if a piece of work is genuinely simple, it's OK if the introduction is quite short.  I have written some reports whose introduction went on for many pages, and others that were a single paragraph, depending on what needed to be explained and in what detail.